Polars: Advanced cross sectional trading algorithm
I have a polars dataframe containing stock returns as well as cross-sectional ranks in a tidy/long pl.DataFrame.
import polars as pl

prices = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "symbol": [
            *["symbol1"] * 7,
            *["symbol2"] * 6,
            *["symbol3"] * 6,
            *["symbol4"] * 7,
        ],
        "date": [
            "2023-12-30", "2023-12-31", "2024-01-03", "2024-01-04", "2024-01-05", "2024-01-06", "2024-01-07",
            "2023-12-30", "2024-01-03", "2024-01-04", "2024-01-05", "2024-01-06", "2024-01-07",
            "2023-12-30", "2023-12-31", "2024-01-03", "2024-01-04", "2024-01-05", "2024-01-07",
            "2023-12-30", "2023-12-31", "2024-01-03", "2024-01-04", "2024-01-05", "2024-01-06", "2024-01-07",
        ],
        "price": [
            100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 100,
            200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250,
            3000, 3100, 3200, 3300, 3400, 3700,
            1000, 1050, 1080, 1090, 1300, 1350, 1400,
        ],
    }
)

shape: (26, 3)
┌─────────┬────────────┬───────┐
│ symbol  ┆ date       ┆ price │
│ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ str     ┆ str        ┆ i64   │
╞═════════╪════════════╪═══════╡
│ symbol1 ┆ 2023-12-30 ┆ 100   │
│ symbol1 ┆ 2023-12-31 ┆ 105   │
│ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-03 ┆ 110   │
│ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-04 ┆ 115   │
│ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-05 ┆ 120   │
│ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-06 ┆ 125   │
│ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-07 ┆ 100   │
│ symbol2 ┆ 2023-12-30 ┆ 200   │
│ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-03 ┆ 210   │
│ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-04 ┆ 220   │
│ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-05 ┆ 230   │
│ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-06 ┆ 240   │
│ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-07 ┆ 250   │
│ symbol3 ┆ 2023-12-30 ┆ 3000  │
│ symbol3 ┆ 2023-12-31 ┆ 3100  │
│ symbol3 ┆ 2024-01-03 ┆ 3200  │
│ symbol3 ┆ 2024-01-04 ┆ 3300  │
│ symbol3 ┆ 2024-01-05 ┆ 3400  │
│ symbol3 ┆ 2024-01-07 ┆ 3700  │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2023-12-30 ┆ 1000  │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2023-12-31 ┆ 1050  │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-03 ┆ 1080  │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-04 ┆ 1090  │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-05 ┆ 1300  │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-06 ┆ 1350  │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-07 ┆ 1400  │
└─────────┴────────────┴───────┘

A simple cross-sectional trading algorithm would be something like this:

Identify the best-performing symbol in a period (here: rank returns over two periods over all symbols for every date).
Insert (buy) the symbol and put it into your portfolio.
Repeat the process for every period (date).

The actual results of the above algo can be computed as follows, whereas the column in_portfolio shows the actual signal.
    returns_ranked = (
        prices.with_columns(pl.col("price").pct_change(2).over("symbol").alias("return"))
        .with_columns(
            rank=pl.col("return")
            .rank(descending=True, method="random")
            .over("date")
            .cast(pl.UInt8)
        )
        .with_columns(in_portfolio=pl.when(pl.col("rank") == 1).then(True).otherwise(False))
    )
    
    shape: (22, 6)
    ┌─────────┬────────────┬───────┬──────────┬──────┬──────────────┐
    │ symbol  ┆ date       ┆ price ┆ return   ┆ rank ┆ in_portfolio │
    │ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ ---          │
    │ str     ┆ str        ┆ i64   ┆ f64      ┆ u8   ┆ bool         │
    ╞═════════╪════════════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════╪══════════════╡
    │ symbol1 ┆ 2023-12-30 ┆ 100   ┆ null     ┆ null ┆ false        │
    │ symbol1 ┆ 2023-12-31 ┆ 105   ┆ null     ┆ null ┆ false        │
    │ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-03 ┆ 110   ┆ 0.1      ┆ 1    ┆ true         │
    │ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-04 ┆ 115   ┆ 0.095238 ┆ 2    ┆ false        │
    │ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-05 ┆ 120   ┆ 0.090909 ┆ 3    ┆ false        │
    │ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-06 ┆ 125   ┆ 0.086957 ┆ 3    ┆ false        │
    │ symbol2 ┆ 2023-12-30 ┆ 200   ┆ null     ┆ null ┆ false        │
    │ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-03 ┆ 210   ┆ null     ┆ null ┆ false        │
    │ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-04 ┆ 220   ┆ 0.1      ┆ 1    ┆ true         │
    │ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-05 ┆ 230   ┆ 0.095238 ┆ 2    ┆ false        │
    │ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-06 ┆ 240   ┆ 0.090909 ┆ 2    ┆ false        │
    │ symbol3 ┆ 2023-12-30 ┆ 3000  ┆ null     ┆ null ┆ false        │
    │ symbol3 ┆ 2023-12-31 ┆ 3100  ┆ null     ┆ null ┆ false        │
    │ symbol3 ┆ 2024-01-03 ┆ 3200  ┆ 0.066667 ┆ 3    ┆ false        │
    │ symbol3 ┆ 2024-01-04 ┆ 3300  ┆ 0.064516 ┆ 3    ┆ false        │
    │ symbol3 ┆ 2024-01-05 ┆ 3400  ┆ 0.0625   ┆ 4    ┆ false        │
    │ symbol4 ┆ 2023-12-30 ┆ 1000  ┆ null     ┆ null ┆ false        │
    │ symbol4 ┆ 2023-12-31 ┆ 1050  ┆ null     ┆ null ┆ false        │
    │ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-03 ┆ 1080  ┆ 0.08     ┆ 2    ┆ false        │
    │ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-04 ┆ 1090  ┆ 0.038095 ┆ 4    ┆ false        │
    │ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-05 ┆ 1300  ┆ 0.203704 ┆ 1    ┆ true         │
    │ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-06 ┆ 1350  ┆ 0.238532 ┆ 1    ┆ true         │
    └─────────┴────────────┴───────┴──────────┴──────┴──────────────┘

Just to show how to "normally" print a cross-sectional ranking, you can do
returns_ranked.pivot(on="symbol", index=["date"], values="rank")

shape: (7, 5)
┌────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ date       ┆ symbol1 ┆ symbol2 ┆ symbol3 ┆ symbol4 │
│ ---        ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str        ┆ u8      ┆ u8      ┆ u8      ┆ u8      │
╞════════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 2023-12-30 ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    │
│ 2023-12-31 ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    │
│ 2024-01-03 ┆ 1       ┆ null    ┆ 3       ┆ 2       │
│ 2024-01-04 ┆ 2       ┆ 1       ┆ 3       ┆ 4       │
│ 2024-01-05 ┆ 3       ┆ 2       ┆ 4       ┆ 1       │
│ 2024-01-06 ┆ 3       ┆ 2       ┆ null    ┆ 1       │
│ 2024-01-07 ┆ 4       ┆ 2       ┆ 1       ┆ 3       │
└────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘

Now, let's make this algorithm a bit more advanced. Rather than simply buying the best performing symbol, the new algorithm looks like this:

Identify the two best-performing symbols in a period (here: rank returns over two periods over all symbols for every date).
Insert (buy) the symbols and put them into your portfolio.
In the next period, you only sell the symbol(s) if they have a rank less than 3. Only then the highest ranked symbol(s) at that period will replace the previous symbols.

The issue here is that this new algorithm always depends on the previous period. We need to know which symbols have been in the portfolio in the previous period in order to check if their current rank is less than 3. That is, we introduce a path dependency.
I am looking for a vectorized solution. I am potentially working with a huge dataset.
Here's the output I am looking for:
shape: (26, 6)
┌─────────┬────────────┬───────┬───────────┬──────┬──────────────┐
│ symbol  ┆ date       ┆ price ┆ return    ┆ rank ┆ in_portfolio │
│ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---  ┆ ---          │
│ str     ┆ str        ┆ i64   ┆ f64       ┆ u8   ┆ bool         │
╞═════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═══════════╪══════╪══════════════╡
│ symbol1 ┆ 2023-12-30 ┆ 100   ┆ null      ┆ null ┆ null         │
│ symbol1 ┆ 2023-12-31 ┆ 105   ┆ null      ┆ null ┆ null         │
│ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-03 ┆ 110   ┆ 0.1       ┆ 1    ┆ true         │
│ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-04 ┆ 115   ┆ 0.095238  ┆ 2    ┆ true         │
│ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-05 ┆ 120   ┆ 0.090909  ┆ 3    ┆ true         │
│ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-06 ┆ 125   ┆ 0.086957  ┆ 3    ┆ true         │
│ symbol1 ┆ 2024-01-07 ┆ 100   ┆ -0.166667 ┆ 4    ┆ false        │
│ symbol2 ┆ 2023-12-30 ┆ 200   ┆ null      ┆ null ┆ null         │
│ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-03 ┆ 210   ┆ null      ┆ null ┆ null         │
│ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-04 ┆ 220   ┆ 0.1       ┆ 1    ┆ true         │
│ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-05 ┆ 230   ┆ 0.095238  ┆ 2    ┆ true         │
│ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-06 ┆ 240   ┆ 0.090909  ┆ 2    ┆ true         │
│ symbol2 ┆ 2024-01-07 ┆ 250   ┆ 0.086957  ┆ 2    ┆ true         │
│ symbol3 ┆ 2023-12-30 ┆ 3000  ┆ null      ┆ null ┆ null         │
│ symbol3 ┆ 2023-12-31 ┆ 3100  ┆ null      ┆ null ┆ null         │
│ symbol3 ┆ 2024-01-03 ┆ 3200  ┆ 0.066667  ┆ 3    ┆ false        │
│ symbol3 ┆ 2024-01-04 ┆ 3300  ┆ 0.064516  ┆ 3    ┆ false        │
│ symbol3 ┆ 2024-01-05 ┆ 3400  ┆ 0.0625    ┆ 4    ┆ false        │
│ symbol3 ┆ 2024-01-07 ┆ 3700  ┆ 0.121212  ┆ 1    ┆ true         │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2023-12-30 ┆ 1000  ┆ null      ┆ null ┆ null         │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2023-12-31 ┆ 1050  ┆ null      ┆ null ┆ null         │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-03 ┆ 1080  ┆ 0.08      ┆ 2    ┆ true         │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-04 ┆ 1090  ┆ 0.038095  ┆ 4    ┆ false        │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-05 ┆ 1300  ┆ 0.203704  ┆ 1    ┆ false        │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-06 ┆ 1350  ┆ 0.238532  ┆ 1    ┆ false        │
│ symbol4 ┆ 2024-01-07 ┆ 1400  ┆ 0.076923  ┆ 3    ┆ false        │
└─────────┴────────────┴───────┴───────────┴──────┴──────────────┘

shape: (7, 5)
┌────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ date       ┆ symbol1 ┆ symbol2 ┆ symbol3 ┆ symbol4 │
│ ---        ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     │
│ str        ┆ u8      ┆ u8      ┆ u8      ┆ u8      │
╞════════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ 2023-12-30 ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    │
│ 2023-12-31 ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    ┆ null    │
│ 2024-01-03 ┆ true    ┆ null    ┆ false   ┆ true    │
│ 2024-01-04 ┆ true    ┆ true    ┆ false   ┆ false   │
│ 2024-01-05 ┆ true    ┆ true    ┆ false   ┆ false   │
│ 2024-01-06 ┆ true    ┆ true    ┆ null    ┆ false   │
│ 2024-01-07 ┆ false   ┆ true    ┆ true    ┆ false   │
└────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘


can you show how output for given input should look like?

I added the output of prices.

In general, you can't make a polars expression that will conditionally do something on row n+x based on the result of row n. There are occasionally ways to sidestep this by using cumulative sums and/or forward_fills. To get the desired high performance result you'd either need to use rust plugins or numba. Here's a numba example.

I thought about numba, too. However, as you pointed out in your linked post, numba won't work with strings. I am not completely sure if this is a show-stopper but I probably really need strings when identifying the name of the symbol that has been in the portfolio in the previous period. I am also not sure about the format to use (long/tidy or wide) when assigning columns/structs to the numba function.

You could .hash() strings or cast to Categorical and pass the numerical value in e.g. .to_physical() to use as an "id" which you can map back. A bigger issue however, is you cannot pass a Series that contains null values.
